# Invalid ID Error when trying to access DocumentProperties

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-workspace

When trying to call the Document Properties, my app returns the error: Invalid ID. Document Properties is only called and accessed in one other section of my application, which was working before I wrote the following code. Since this code was written, the previous area has since ceased functioning as well. Here is the error and the code:

`Exception: Invalid ID [line: 3, function: viewRecord, file:`

```
function viewRecord() {
  const properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  const dProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  const record = JSON.parse(dProperties.getProperty("linked_record"));
  if (record !== null && record !== undefined) {
    const url = `${properties.getProperty("instance_url")}/${record.ViewPage}`
    return CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText("View")
      .setOpenLink(
        CardService.newOpenLink()
          .setUrl(url)
          .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)
          .setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.NOTHING)
      );
  }
  return CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("View")
    .setOnClickAction(
      CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("viewRecordError")
    );
}
```

The line 3 here is the document properties line. What would cause this error? I am storing a record in JSON format that I am trying to access.

1. I have tried removing the code, however, the issue persists in the other area where document properties is accessed.
2. I have tried deleting all properties in my application, and the error persists.

Comment: I could be wrong but isn't this code inside of a  standalone script? so there is no container and thus no document

Comment: I apologize for not adding additional context, but the script is part of a workspace addon and was being executed through the UI in Google docs. It should have been picking up the document that was open.

Comment: Yes which means it's in a standalone script and so there is no container document

Comment: It would seem that the issue was my file was a docx and not a gdoc file. I was unaware that the document properties were directly attached to the file itself.

Comment: I did not know that either.  I don't think I've used document properties before.